# Linear extension of a set

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have to find a linear extension of the poset $(X,P)$ where the set

$X = \{2,3,10,21,24,50,210\}$ iff $x$ divides $y$.

For the answer, I got

$\{(2,10),(2,24),(2,50),(2,210),(3,21),(3,24),(3,210),(10,50),(10,210),(21,210)\}$

and I think that is it because every $x$ value divides $y$. I wanted to know that this isn't just a total order as well, right? I just want to double check. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is not a linear extension of the ordering because it is not a total ordering. An example of a linear extension, meaning a total ordering compatible with the given partial ordering, would be
$$2<3<10<21<24<50<210$$
which is actually just the set listed in increasing order.

Exhaustively listing the elements of the relation isn't really something one should spend a lot of time doing because they get big fast. The linear extension has $21$ elements such as $(2,3)$, $(2,10)$, $(2,21)$, $\ldots$, $(3,10)$, $(3,21)$, $\ldots$ or in general $(a,b)$ where $a$ occurs before $b$ in the list above.

Comment: then how would a total ordering look like then? and what makes a linear extension different from a total order?

Comment: @Miriam A total ordering must have every element comparable with any other element, meaning if $x\neq y$ then either $(x,y)$ or $(y,x)$ is in the relation.

Comment: @Miriam A linear extension is a total ordering associated to a partial ordering that "extends" it, in the sense that any existing relations are preserved. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_extension

Comment: Could you show me the total order for this relation in this example above because I want a better understanding of total order? Thanks!

Comment: @Miriam I'm not sure what you mean by "total order" in this context.

Comment: Like, how would I write a total order for the relation of "x divides y"?

Comment: In general, "x divides y" is not a total order. A total order is a partial ordering in which every element is comparable to every other element. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order If you mean to actually write out the elements of the partial ordering, they would be $(x,y)$ where $y=mx$ for some $m$.

Comment: Oh okay, I read the definition incorrectly in my notes, I meant totality, I see the difference now. But another question I have in mind, is that my notes says "A linear extension of a poset (X,P) is a total order L on X such that if (x,y) ∈ P, then (x,y) ∈ L", is this just for binary relations?

Comment: Yes. If you review the definition of a partial order you'll see that it's a binary relation.

Comment: Then it says "if (x,y) ∈ P, then (x,y) ∈ L", so does that means every element in P has to be a linear extension?

Comment: No a linear extension is an ordering of the whole set, not an element of the set.

Comment: I think what Miriam wants is to see all of the ordered pairs of the relation given by the linear extension written out explicitly.